# Exclude part of a wordpress post from appearing the rss feed

Tags: wordpress, rss

I want to exclude a few lines of most wordpress posts from appearing in the rss feed.

For example, if the body of my post was

```
<embed>Some file</embed>
Hello World
```

How would I exclude the `<embed>Some file</embed>` from appearing in the feed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this you should use a filter to remove the unwanted elements in a post before its sent to the RSS feed.

Add this to your functions.php to register the function:

```
<?php add_filter( "the_content_feed", "filter_away_embed_function" ) ?>
```

Add the following code to either a plugin or to functions.php aswell:

```
<?php 
   function filter_away_embed_function($content) {
     $content = preg_replace('#(<embed.*?>).*?(</embed>)#', '$1$2', $content)
     return $content; 
   } ?>
```

The function will strip away all text within `<embed>` and `</embed>`.